# set columnsep in geometry and multicols separately

Tags: multicol, geometry

Inside a two column document, I am using the multicols environment in order to save space on small questions. However, the width of columnsep that I am using at page level is apparently the same that multicol uses. Is there anyway to fix that ?

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2 cm, bottom=2 cm, left=2 cm, right=2 cm,twocolumn,a4paper,landscape]{geometry}

\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

Which of the following fractions are equal to $\dfrac{5}{3}$ ?
\begin{multicols}{5}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\dfrac{45}{27}$
\item $\dfrac{54}{33}$
\item $\dfrac{90}{54}$
\item $\dfrac{40}{25}$
\item $\dfrac{0,05}{0,03}$
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\columnsep` is only used by the main `twocolumn` in `\twocolumn` (or `\begin{document}`) to calculate the `\columnwidth` so you can set it to a new value locally before the `multicolumn` without affecting the page layout.

Comment: Thanks, I should have tried this before !